# If input value is blank, assign a value of “null” when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I'm fairly new to the form validation process. How do I return a value of **null** if input value is **an empty string**, when a form is submitted?

As you can see from the example below I have three options for verifying a user's identity. Based on the radio button selected, a user can then proceed to enter the relevant details. Upon submission of the form, I want the empty fields (the other 2 options not selected) to return a value of "null" or "empty" rather than ",,,". Can you please assist in resolving this issue.

**See code example below:**

```
<TR><TD colspan="2" align="left">
            <TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="5" style="background-color:<%=colourblock%>; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:16px; display:block; margin-bottom:10px;"><TR><TD style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:18px;">Step 10 - Provide identification</TD></TR></TABLE><BR /><strong>Please confirm your identity using one of the below Government issued identification.</strong><BR /><BR />

             <TR><TD width="253"><input type="radio" name="IdentityType" id="IdentityType" value="**Australian driver's licence number**">
                <label for="IdentityType">Australian driver's licence number:</label> </TD><TD width="672"><span id="sprytextfield1">
  <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue"  value="" /></span></TD></TR>

            <TR><TD><input type="radio" name="IdentityType" id="IdentityType" value="**Australian passport number**"><label for="IdentityType">Australian passport number:</label></TD><TD>
                   <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue"  value="" /></TD></TR>


            <TR><TD><input type="radio" name="IdentityType" id="IdentityType" value="**Immicard number**"><label for="IdentityType">Immicard number: </label></TD><TD>
                <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue"  value="" /></TD></TR>



                <TR><TD colspan="2" align="left"><BR >
If you don't hold any of these identification, you will need to attach certified copies of relevant proof of identity documents as outlined on the proof of identity guide on <a  href="http://www.plum.com.au" target="_blank"><strong>plum.com.au</strong></a><BR /><BR />

                  </TD></TR>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question and show us your code so far, and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: show us something more

Comment: What is being submitted now when your input is blank? Show us what you've tried with your code and where it's giving you trouble.

Comment: @JanR I have provided an example above. Could you please look at it and provide feedback?

Comment: @JishnuVS see example above.

Comment: @Jecoms see above.

Comment: Why are you giving multiple fields the same ID? Since that is not valid HTML, it's bound to give unexpected results eventually, even if it seems to work right now.

Answer (score 0):

when processing the code, it'll always post as an empty string (when using classic asp vbscript). if you the value to be null, just assign it to null like so:

```
dim IdentityValue : IdentityValue = Request.Form("IdentityValue")
if IdentityValue = "" then IdentityValue = null
```

now IdentityValue will be null